# Navigation Bar of Vimeo

Tags: jquery, html

When you go to vimeo.com you see a navigation bar, and when you put your mouse over the Explore and Help menu the menu falls down very smoothly, so I'm curious how the Vimeo developers have created that and which jQuery plugin they use.

Answer (score 0):

They use no jQuery-- indeed, no Javascript at all.

Instead, they use CSS transitions. Example:

```
.a .e .d {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```